# How to open Google play books from a button click using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a app in Xamarin.Forms that has a button for books. I want it to open iBooks if the OS is iOS and Google play books if it is android

I have the iBooks Part down but How would I open google play books from the button click in the android version of the app?

Heres my xaml code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" MinimumHeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Button  Image="books.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="OpenBooks" />
              <Button  Image="settings.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="gotosettings" />
          </StackLayout>
```

Heres My C# code:

```
public void OpenBooks(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Device.OS)
    {
        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
            Device.OpenUri(new Uri("itms-books"));
            break;
            case TargetPlatform.Android:
            //open google play books code here
            break;
     }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thank in advance!

Comment: Do you know the package name of Play Books? If so, you can do as read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android). If not, I am not sure you can achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the android platform you should know the package name of google play books and check if it is installed already.

In the PCL part you can not achieve it by `Device.OpenUri("packagename");`

You should use the dependency service to open the google play books app, and The google play books app package name is `com.google.android.apps.books`
:

**In the PCL side define the interface:**

```
namespace OpenBooks_Demo
{
    public interface OpenBookInterface
    {
        void openBooks();
    }
}
```

**In the andorid side implements the interface:**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(OpenBookImp))]
namespace OpenBooks_Demo.Droid
{
    public class OpenBookImp :  Java.Lang.Object, OpenBookInterface
    {
        public OpenBookImp() { }
        public void openBooks()
        {
            var ctx = Forms.Context;

            Intent launchIntent = new Intent();
            launchIntent = ctx.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.books");
            if (launchIntent != null)
            {
                ctx.StartActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    ctx.StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + "com.google.android.apps.books")));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ctx.StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.google.android.apps.books")));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And then call the openBooks method in the PCL side:**

```
public void OpenBooks(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Device.OS)
            {
                case TargetPlatform.iOS:
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("itms-books"));
                    break;
                case TargetPlatform.Android:
                    DependencyService.Get<OpenBookInterface>().openBooks();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

In my android device I have installed the google play books:
[image]

Comment: @Mika, How about opening book to view?